# GCMBaseIntentService callback only in Root Package

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I've implemented GCM in my app and I've come across a strange issue.
When my overriding `IntentService` for `GCMBaseIntentService` sits in my root package it works fine. I reference it in my manifest with `.MyGCMIntentService`.
The root package would be `com.example.rootpackage`

When I move my intent service to a different package, such as `com.example.rootpackage.service` the intent service is never called. At this point I would update my manifest to point to `com.example.rootpackage.service.MyGCMIntentService` and no dice.

Am I missing something in Google's documentation on locating it or is this just how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be in the root package :

> This intent service will be called by the GCMBroadcastReceiver (which is provided by the GCM library), as shown in the next step. It must be a subclass of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService, must contain a public constructor, and should be named **my_app_package.GCMIntentService** (unless you use a subclass of GCMBroadcastReceiver that overrides the method used to name the service).

(quote taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/helper.html))

EDIT :

As the documentation says, you can change it if you use a subclass of `GCMBroadcastReceiver` which overrides `getDefaultIntentServiceClassName` :

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMBroadcastReceiver";
    private static boolean mReceiverSet = false;

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive: " + intent.getAction());
        // do a one-time check if app is using a custom GCMBroadcastReceiver
        if (!mReceiverSet) {
            mReceiverSet = true;
            String myClass = getClass().getName();
            if (!myClass.equals(GCMBroadcastReceiver.class.getName())) {
                GCMRegistrar.setRetryReceiverClassName(myClass);
            }
        }
        String className = getGCMIntentServiceClassName(context);
        Log.v(TAG, "GCM IntentService class: " + className);
        // Delegates to the application-specific intent service.
        GCMBaseIntentService.runIntentInService(context, intent, className);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null /* data */, null /* extra */);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the class name of the intent service that will handle GCM messages.
     */
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return getDefaultIntentServiceClassName(context);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the default class name of the intent service that will handle GCM
     * messages.
     */
    static final String getDefaultIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        String className = context.getPackageName() +
                DEFAULT_INTENT_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME;
        return className;
    }
}
```